# Add OTP verification in WordPress(WooCommerce) in Registration Form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I was working with this woocommerce theme (Sober) and wanted to add custom OTP verification after the user registers to my website.

All I want is that when user fill up the registration form and submit, an OTP is send to his/her phone(Don't wana use third party plugin). Once the user verifies the OTP than only the account be created.

I have added few custom field to my woocommerce form, but don't know how to redirect to otp verification without the form being saved unless otp is verified.

I am pretty new to WordPress and WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think when you are using any framework try to integrate certain third party tools by yourself instead of using plugins. There are pros and cons to this.

Its a pretty old question but thought this may be help for others. You can use a free service from Facebook called AccountKit for integration of OTP in multiple platforms.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit

There are other paid and good options as well, but FBs AccountKit is really easy to integrate at-least till the time FB lifts support from AccountKit.

Hope this helps.